# Is there a way to publish website on IIS without application recycle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web, publish

We need to make a quick change to fix a problem on our site. However, when we want to replace a DLL, we need to restart ASP.NET MVC application for recompilation which causes problems like session variables erased etc.

Maybe some strategy exists for publishing website without process rebuilding so users will not loose their work. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is not. You should have thought about that in the planning of your application. You can make improvements in the feature in order to save your session vars in a db or smth if they are so important to you. But updating DLL, web.config, etc. are the same with restarting your server for any application. In these situations, being stored in the memory, everything is erased for good.

That's what I know. If someone has an opposite opinion, I am happy to see contributing answers :)